# Understanding iterator default value

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I'm having trouble understanding why the third `next(w)` executes, and `StopIteration` exception get raised at the next one and not at the third.

From my understanding, `next(w)` should raise `StopIteration` whenever any of its expressions are exhausted, and it happens whenever `next(y, 'b')` reaches the default value, which is `'b'`.

Why does the iterator returns the default value twice?

```
x = iter(range(3))
y = iter(range(3))
w = ([next(y, "a"), next(y, "b")] for z in x)
try:
    print(next(w)) # -> prints [0, 1]
    print(next(w)) # -> prints [2, 'b']
    print(next(w)) # -> prints ['a', 'b']
    print(next(w)) # raise StopIteration
    print(next(w))
except:
    print("7") # -> prints '7'
```

Comment: I think your exception comes because you have exhausted the `w` iterator, not the `x` or `y` iterators (as you have no default value for `w`)

Comment: What do you mean "any of it's expressions"? `next` will raise `StopIteration` when the *iterator you are calling on it decides to do that*. In this case, that iterator is `w`, which is a generator expression, that is iterating over `x`, which is itself an iterator over a range with size 3... so not surprisingly, three things are printed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the iterator returns the default value twice?

The iterator returns the default value as many times at it is called, not only twice. The problem occurs because you defined `x` and `w` as follows:

```
x = iter(range(3))
y = iter(range(3))
w = ([next(y, "a"), next(y, "b")] for z in x)
```

Your `w` list has 3 entries (it iterates over the 3 elements in `x`), and when you call `next(w)` a fourth time, it throws an exception. Try setting `x = iter(range(5))`, and you will see that you can now call `print(next(w))` 5 times. The inner `next` calls will return the default values as many times as called.

To confirm this, just output `w` after creating it, so you can see its contents:

```
x = iter(range(3))
y = iter(range(3))
w = ([next(y, "a"), next(y, "b")] for z in x)
list(w)

> [[0, 1], [2, 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Your `w` list has 3 entries"?

Comment: Try `list(w)` so you can see the contents of `w`. You will see that there are 3 entries. If you call `next(w)` 4 times, then you get an exception: You only have 3 entries.

Comment: "The iterator returns the default value as many times at it is called, not only twice. " that's what i needed, didn't knew that. thank you!